# writeBuffer() error when I try to download excel file with huge data in Exceljs

Tags: reactjs, memory, buffer, exceljs

I'm trying to write excel file and download it by using ExcelJs in React. It's working well when I try with the small data but it's not good in the huge data using. i.e: I've 250K,500K data rows.
btw, I've other project with same huge data and it's working well because it's using **xslx-populate** package. when I try **writeBuffer**() in Exceljs, the chrome browser has been halt and warn AW,Snap!. let me know who have experience in writterBuffer() in ExcelJs.
[here is attached code snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fehZq.png)

Comment: here is code snap. The Chrome browser has been halt with AW,Snap! and can't get buffer array
 workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
      const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "applicationi/xlsx" });
      // const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
      saveAs(blob, `${fileName} Reservix Detailauswertung Zutrittskontrolle (TEST).xlsx`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("writeFile Fail:", err);
    });